# Does anyone know how to write this algorithm in COBOL: sum array values with sum equal to X

Tags: algorithm, cobol

I have 12 accounting amounts associated with two different invoices presented in this order:  -18.91, -8.48, -3654.47, -3379.07, -648.91, -2025.30, -1121.27, -1132.26, -22.68, -324.45, -861.50, and -24.31; of these, which combination of these accounting amounts equals the invoice amount -8574.87; the remaining amounts should equal the other invoice amount of -4646.74.  Is there a mathematical formula that could be written in COBOL to determine this result.

01 Acct-table     value spaces.
   05  acct-entry  occurs 50 times
       10  acct-amt  PIC S9(12)V99

01 invoice-table   value spaces.
    05  inv-entry occurs 50 times
        10  inv-amt   PIC S9(12)V99

Comment: The code is easy. Where is your algorithm? Sit down with pencil and the back of an old listing, and work out how to do it "by hand". Then think about how to implement that with COBOL code. Presumably you are on a course, so for the implementation you should be using techniques you've learned so far. But first, work out how to do it. Code comes later. I'd go for the -4646.74 amount, there will be fewer possibilities, so it'll run faster. It can be convenient to sort the data, It's just permutations with a limit.

Comment: Yes, I have been able to figure this out on paper.  I need a routine in COBOL that my program can use for this situation that comes up quite often.  This is only one example of money amounts I encounter that are in various order.  -18.91 -3654.47 -648.91 -324.45 = -4646.74.

Comment: Good work. So, you need to update your question with what you have come up with in pseudo-code and show how you've attempted to implement that in COBOL and where you are stuck with it.

Comment: That's my issue.  I'm looking for a formula or algorithm and its syntax to code in COBOL that can calculate this scenario I provided earlier.  Does such a formula exist that can be written in COBOL?

Comment: Of course. The one you came up with can be written in COBOL, if you use the edit link under your question and add it there. As previously mentioned, you should give at least some starting point for how you would approach the code as well.

Comment: I didn't use a formula to find these amounts.  I played with the numbers until I got the result I needed (not efficient).  I'm looking for a way to figure this out mathematically.  Since this situation happens periodically with invoices I receive in my pay application, I am reaching out to anyone who would know how to set this up in COBOL using the example I provided above.

Comment: Why would you get that with invoices? Wouldn't you have an invoice number? Update your question please to explain how you need to use this and show some sample data (beyond just the amount) that you have. What do you have, one payment covering several invoices? You can "brute force" it, but you have to be aware that there may be multiple answers, so that's not really a big help.

Comment: I don't have the invoice number to link the lines of accounting to it; hence my problem.  The lines of accounting come in on a separate file and some times are scrambled as in the example I provided and I must figure which one(s) belong to which invoice.  Each line of accounting has an amount associated with it.  I know ahead of time what the invoice amounts are.  The above math problem I provided originally is an example of one scenario I recently received.

Comment: Imagine you have 12 items of -100 each, and you have to match to 600 and 600. How are you going to do it? Replace 3 of your items with -39.22, -16.01 and -23.31. How are you going to do it? There's either something else you are being given which will allow you to do something reasonable, or this is nothing reasonable you can do except get more information provided. Otherwise it is brute force, with multiple answers, and a guess. You can't do it with just amounts. You have 12! (12 factorial) combinations. Possible multiple answers. Show your data and definitions.

Comment: If you go with @cobp's answer, it'll do what you want. Try to take account of my comments on it. I'm really sure your data should give you a better solution, but that's not cobp's fault.

Comment: You can extend it, with care, to other than two amounts. But again, I really can't see how you get this in an accounting system. Class exercise, yes.

Comment: This question is actually quite profound. It is very closely related to the Subset Sum Problem which is known to be NP-Complete (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). Finding the answer subset essentially requires an exhaustive search of all subsets. A set with n members generates 2**n subsets (not feasible to compute for large n). So the solution proposed by @cobp is pretty much as good a solution as you will find. The COBOL coding could use some improvement but the approach was not unreasonable for small sets.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2^12 different combinations of accounts. Bruteforce approach 
of all combinations can be implemented using bitmask.(COBOL implemention
would be not that straight forward), An approximate pseudo code 
to get the overview as follows.

```
for b=0 to 2^12 - 1 do #each combination

  sum1 = 0
  sum2=  0
  for i=0 to 11 do   # which elements are included

     if (b && (1<<i) != 0)
        sum1 = sum1+ arr[i+1]
     else
        sum2 = sum2+ arr[i+1] 
    end
  end
  if (sum1= -8574.87 and sum2= -4646.74)
       print "got it"
  end
end
```

Cobol implementation of it(freeformat compiled and tested using a web compiler). Bitmask /bit positions are manually calculated(by repeaedly dividing by 2 and taking remainder).
Following combination is the answer:
-8,48+-3379,07+-2025,30+-1121,27+-1132,26+-22,68+-861,50+-24,31

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. ACCSUM.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  ACCOUNTS.
    05  ACC-X       PIC S9(4)v99 COMP-3 
                    OCCURS 12 TIMES.
01  B               PIC 9(06) comp.
01  bx              PIC 9(06) comp.
01  pos             pic 9(06) comp.
01  sum1            pic s9(8)v99 comp-3.
01  sum2            pic s9(8)v99 comp-3.
01  r               pic 9(06) comp.
01  res             pic 9(06) comp. 
01  comb            pic x(15) value space.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
0000-MAIN SECTION.
    PERFORM 0100-init
    perform 0200-process
    STOP RUN.
0100-init section.
    move  -18.91  to ACC-X(1)
    move  -8.48   to ACC-X(2)
    move  -3654.47 to ACC-X(3)
    move   -3379.07 to ACC-X(4)
    move   -648.91 to ACC-X(5)
    move  -2025.30 to ACC-X(6)
    move  -1121.27 to ACC-X(7)
    move  -1132.26 to ACC-X(8)
    move  -22.68 to ACC-X(9)
    move  -324.45 to ACC-X(10)
    move  -861.50 to ACC-X(11)
    move  -24.31 to ACC-X(12)
    exit.
0200-process section.

    perform varying b from 0 by 1
      until b>4095
       compute bx=b
       compute pos=0
       move zero to sum1 sum2
       perform until bx= zero
            divide bx by 2 giving res remainder r

            if ( r <> zero )
              compute sum1 = sum1+ acc-x ( pos + 1 )
              move '1' to comb(pos + 1 : 1)
            else
              compute sum2 = sum2+ acc-x ( pos + 1 )
              move '0' to comb(pos + 1 : 1)
            end-if

            compute bx = bx / 2
            add 1 to pos

       end-perform

       if (sum1 = -8574.87 ) then
         display "combination :" comb "-Sum2=" sum2
       end-if
    end-perform
    exit.
```

Comment: If you want to do some COBOL in your own time, have a look at GnuCOBOL at SourceForge. Much more flexible to have your own. GnuCOBOL was formerly OpenCOBOL which may well be what you used online.

Comment: It's a nice idea. I assume you know how it works. If the two amounts sought are zero and the-sum-of-all-12, such that your search value is zero, it will fail. Not a big problem, as if one of the amounts sought is zero, you can easily short-cut the whole thing. If three amounts are sought, or n-amounts, it can still be made to work (base-3, or base-n). It relies on all individual values being constituent at the moment, but even that could be dealt with. It will find multiple solutions for the combinations of values.

Comment: There are some things about your COBOL. I assume you're fairly new to COBOL, but are familiar with other languages? You divide bx by two twice. Having used a solution where the pos-es are encoded, no need to store them as you go along, but use the current b value and de-code that. Your two remaining COMPUTEs are better as simple ADDs. To avoid the miss I mentioned, start your outer-loop from 1 (and add one to the terminal value). Also can be avoided by doing the inner-loop a different way, like 12 TIMES. Outer loop could be 4096 times, and control b yourself.

Comment: If two amounts are sought, rather than relying on all the values being constituent, for each "hit" first time through, do the lot again, but removing the constituents of the hit from the table. I'm not sure that you know that `exit` does nothing. It's fast enough, but the changes would make it clearer to the reader (important) and faster. And more flexible.  For information, if you happen to be using Enterprise COBOL V5, the compiler will generate a shift for your divide by two.

Comment: No, I am not new to COBOL, but not familiar with doing complex math equations with the language which led me here.  I have two tables: one for the accounting amounts and one for the invoice amounts.  The sum of all the accounting amounts will equal the sum of all the invoice amounts; no extra money left over.  Usually, the accounting amounts are listed in the order the invoice amounts are listed.  Knowing the invoice amount, I can read thru the subscripted accounting table until the sum of the accounting amounts equals that paticular invoice amount.  Not a problem.  But....

Comment: Now and then, the accounting amounts are not listed in the order of the invoice amounts.  For instance, I will get acct amt (1) for invoice 1, acct amt (2) for invoice 2, acct amt (3) for invoice 1,  acct amt (4) for invoice 2. Here, invoice 2 has its amts out of order.  Usually, this situation results in manual intervention to determine what amts go where.  This is why I was looking for a program solution to figure out systematically.  Any unused amounts in the tables are initialized to zero.  The number of invoices and acct amts can vary from instance to instance.

Comment: +1 Your brute force approach is about as good a solution as will be found for small set sizes (see my comment on the question). The COBOL really needs work, but contains all the essential elements: Using a counter to generate a full set of bit masks then using an inner loop with DIVIDE by 2 and REMAINDER to peal off bits to identify the subset for summing. Some advanced algorithmic approaches could have been used (eg dynamic programming) but do not fundamentally change the "high cost" of computing the ansewer.